# Display products in list. How do I place an pagination div at bottom with 100%?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my JsFiddle (code posted below also): http://jsfiddle.net/zsy0anso/2/

I have products displayed in divs and I want a pagination div with width: 100% to be displayed after all products have been displayed. How?

```
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="pagination">pagination</div>

.product:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    content:    "";
    height: 315px;
    margin-left:    0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position:   absolute;
    width:      208px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.product:after {
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    width:      210px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}

.pagination {
    /* How do I "clear" this div, place it below so I can display an pagination? */
}
```

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS

```
.pagination {
    clear:both; float:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding clear: both; to .pagination

CSS

```
.product {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 194px;
    padding: 30px 30px 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.product:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    content:    "";
    height: 315px;
    margin-left:    0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position:   absolute;
    width:      208px;
    z-index: -1;

}

.product:after {
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    width:      210px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}

.pagination {
    clear: both; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="product">product</div>
<div class="pagination">pagination</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/8f7tq8jL/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear:both` to `.pagination`.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsy0anso/3/).